# Java regex - overlapping matches

Tags: java, regex

In the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D+\\d+").matcher("2abc3abc4abc5");
    while (m.find()) {
        allMatches.add(m.group());
    }

    String[] res = allMatches.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
}
```

The result is:

```
[2abc3, 4abc5]
```

**I'd like it to be**

```
[2abc3, 3abc4, 4abc5]
```

**How can it be achieved?**

Comment: You would need to search starting at every index; use the find(int startingIndex) method and search starting at every character position. Of course, then you're likely to find too many matches... Assuming you want to start at every number, you might try combining an iteration over Matcher.find(String.indexOf(digits, index)) for all matching indices.

Comment: I suppose if it's single digits, you could back up from the match starting position and find from there for the next match.

Comment: For input `"12abc13abc14abc15"`, do you want `[12abc13, 2abc13, 13abc14, 3abc14, 14abc15, 4abc15]` or `[12abc13, 13abc14, 14abc15]`?

Comment: @johnchen902: the later. The solution handles this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make the matcher attempt to start its next scan from the latter `\d+`.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D+(\\d+)").matcher("2abc3abc4abc5");
if (m.find()) {
    do {
        allMatches.add(m.group());
    } while (m.find(m.start(1)));
}
```

Comment: To the first two up-voter: the ordinary version contains a bug that if nothing matches, an `IllegalStateException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this is possible in Java, but in PCRE you could do the following:
`(?=(\d+\D+\d+)).`

**Explanation**
The technique is to use a matching group in a lookahead, and then "eat" one character to move forward.

- `(?=` : start of positive lookahead

  - `(` : start matching group 1

    - `\d+` : match a digit one or more times
    - `\D+` : match a non-digit character one or more times
    - `\d+` : match a digit one or more times
  - `)` : end of group 1
- `)` : end of lookahead
- `.` : match anything, this is to "move forward".

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lM2tN5)

---

Thanks to [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089) it really seems to work in Java. You just need to add backslashes and display the first capturing group: `(?=(\\d+\\D+\\d+)).`.
Tested on [www.regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html):

[image]

Comment: @anubhava It gives the right results for PCRE. That's what I stated anyways.

Comment: Yes I just meant that in Java it didn't give expected results.

Comment: @anubhava: I have tested it and it works well, assuming that you add backslashes and you display the first capturing group. downvoter: The downvote has no sens here.

Comment: @anubhava I know but I tested it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and it [works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kPa03.png).

Comment: I know regex is valid but the thing is if you use this in `String#split(regex)` it will produce an empty string at start.

Comment: @anubhava: It's a regex for the find method.

Comment: Not really working. Use `12abc13abc14abc15` as input and the result is `[12abc13, 2abc13, 13abc14, 3abc14, 14abc15, 4abc15]` instead of `[12abc13, 13abc14, 14abc15]`. See my and OP's comments under the question.

Comment: @johnchen902 overlapping matches ! That's what he wanted to begin with ... If that's not the case then `(?=(\d+\D+\d+))\d+` would do [the job](http://regex101.com/r/zI1jQ4)

Comment: @johnchen902: right you must replace the pattern by `(?=((?<!\\d)\\d+\\D+\\d+))` if you don't want overlapped results in your overlapped results. :)

Answer (score 4):

The above solution of HamZa works perfectly in Java. If you want to find a specific pattern in a text all you have to do is:

```java
String regex = "\\d+\\D+\\d+";

String updatedRegex = "(?=(" + regex + ")).";
```

Where the `regex` is the pattern you are looking for and to be overlapping you need to surround it with `(?=(" at the start and ")).` at the end.