# Matching "aa" against "aaaa" returns a count of 2 in java -- I want it to be 3

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to understand pattern matching in Java. However, I am stumped by the output of the code below. It prints a count of 2 while matching "aa" against "aaaa" however I expect it to print 3 because 'a' followed by 'a' happens thrice in the given string. Can anybody explain what's the issue here?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aa");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaa");
int count = 0;
while(m.find())
  count++;
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Doesn't include overlaps.

Comment: A matcher will restart from after the text it has matched; only if the match is empty will it automatically shift one character (to avoid infinite matching). This is pretty much the behaviour of all regex engines

Comment: @fge That is incorrect. Please research "positive lookahead" to see how this can be easily achieved. Here's an answer which covers it in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971681/501113

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matcher will not find overlapping matches.  So since the first match is found at index 0 with a length of two, it won't start looking for the next match until index 2, and the potential match starting at index 1 isn't found.

If you wanted to find overlapping matches you could use `m.find(start)` where `start` is an index one higher than your previous match.  For example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aa");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaa");
int count = 0;
int start = 0;
while(m.find(start)) {
  count++;
  start = m.start() + 1;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW need to place a check on start for overflow.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. By using "positive lookahead", it can easily be achieved. This answer does a fantastic job of explaining how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971681/501113

Answer (score 0):

When searching for literal strings, you can also use `indexOf`:

```
public class Test  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
     String toFind = "aa";
     String toSearch = "aaaa";

     int idxLastFound = 0;
     int foundCount = 0;

     while(idxLastFound <= (toSearch.length() - toFind.length()))  {
        idxLastFound = toSearch.indexOf(toFind, idxLastFound);
        if(idxLastFound == -1)  {
           break;
        }
        System.out.println("Found at " + idxLastFound);
        idxLastFound++;
        foundCount++;
     }

     System.out.println("Found " + foundCount + " times");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java Test
Found at 0
Found at 1
Found at 2
Found 3 times
```