# extract all substring combinations between 2 characters using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I got a `String s = "HFGFHFFHSSH"`. What I want as output is every possible substring combination between 'H'

The output of the above String should be `HFGFH HFFH HSSH`

I tried the following:

```
String s = "HFGFHFFHSSH";  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("H(.*?)H");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Unfortunalety the output is missing one substring resulting in `HFGFH HSSH`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971466/java-regex-overlapping-matches

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh thanks I didn't come across that question in my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a lookahead regex for this and capture the value from inside the lookahead:

```
(?=(H[^H]*H))
```

- `(?=...)` is positive lookahead that asserts presence of text surrounded by `H` on either side
- `(...)` inside the lookahead is for capturing the matched value in group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sy7IZB/3)

**Code:**

```
String s = "HFGFHFFHSSH";  
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(H[^H]*H))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: The regex101 site enlightens me what really is going on in the regex stuff. :)