# Regular Expression for any non-empty consecutive sequence of 0's enclosed between 1

Tags: java, regex

I need to find all the groups in a String having consecutive sequence of 0's enclosed between 1

```
100001abc101 // 2 groups `100001` and `101`
1001ab010abc01001 // 2 groups `1001' and `1001`
1001010001 // 3 groups `1001`, `101` and `10001` --> This is a special case
```

My [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/IGygJj/2) for the same is: `1(0+)1` this is working good for 1st and 2nd case but in 3rd test case It's only matching `1001` and `10001` not `101`

Please suggest what I am missing.

The problem is match starts from the next character of last matched group, it should start from the same matched character itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex - overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971466/java-regex-overlapping-matches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match overlapping matches, you should be using a capturing group inside a lookahead like this:

```
(?=(10+1))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1wLyxu/1)

Since we are only asserting matches instead of matching them, regex engine is able to return all possible combinations of `10+1` even if they are overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

Try a look-behind and look-ahead instead, since you don't actually want to match the 1s:

```
/(?<=1)0+(?=1)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/IGygJj/3

Comment: OP wrote: `1001010001 // 3 groups 1001, 101 and 10001` so surely OP wants `1s` also in the matches.

Comment: Oh, you're probably right. The "enclosed by" wording made me think otherwise. Well, this regular expression should still work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like `(?=(10+1))10+`
where group 1 contains the sequence while
not matching the last 1.

https://regex101.com/r/uH5OrS/1

In general, you'd want to move the position with the last `10+`.
In this case it's not necessary, but I wouldn't get into the habit
of not including it, it will bite you some day.