# Finding a match inbetween two matches using the same capture groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've been doing regex for years but apparently I've never come across this issue before and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Here is a basic regex to show the crux of my problem -

`(\d)(.*?)(\d)`

So if I have this string -

`aaa 4 bbb 5 ccc 6 ddd 7 eee`

I get two matches out of this (demoed here @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uxNekS/1)) -

1. `4 bbb 5` with capture groups `4, bbb , 5`
2. `6 ddd 7` with capture groups `6, ddd , 7`

but there should be a third match inbetween the two matches that use the last capture group from the first match and the first capture group from the last match.

- `5 ccc 6` with capture groups `5, ccc , 6`

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Java, c# **and** python? Please choose one language or none if it should be language agnostic

Comment: In this particular case I dont care what language it is answered in - its a theory question for me and I work in 4-5 languages daily

Comment: @Nefariis In that case just the regex tags will do.  I fixed that for you.  Also you want to look into look ahead and look behind.

Comment: Every language has it's own implementation of Regex, it does matter.

Comment: It's about how regex matches are done. Once you advance to 5 and a match was found, you don't go back.

Comment: @Sach And that's why we have look aheads, so that we don't advance further than we want to.

Comment: Also this was definitely a properly asked question - I have what I'm working with, what it does, what I'm trying to do, and a linked demo. The only reason I attached any languages to it at all was because stack overflow itself said "with regex questions you should tag a language with it." - And I just personally dont care which language, so I said the ones that I work in the most

Comment: So think of a regex as consuming character by character. Once your cursor moves past `5` in your string, you've found a match. But now your cursor is sitting at _after_ the `5`. So you can't go back and start _before_ the `5`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971466/java-regex-overlapping-matches

Comment: @juharr true, I should have said it's the way _this particular_ regex was written.

Comment: @Nefariis Yes, one language because regular expression can work differently in different language.  Spamming languages is never the answer.

Comment: @juharr - out of curiosity, does `(\d)(.*?)(?=(\d))` work the same across Java, C#, and Python? ... so would it seem that the way I framed the question would make the regex answer fairly agnostic?

Comment: Note that your demo is using PHP syntax (see the options down the left hand side)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to use look ahead so that you matches don't advance past the desired values you want the next match to start with.

```
(\d)(.*?)(?=(\d))
```

You could also change it to search for non-numeric values instead of using the lazy search

```
(\d)(\D*)(?=(\d))
```

And here's the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxNekS/2) for whomever thought this was wrong.

Comment: Or `(\d)([^\d]+)(?=(\d))` which is more efficient.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness The important part to make it work is the look ahead.  Anything else is just a suggestion.

Comment: Sure, mine was just a suggestion.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Actually using `\D` would make even more sense like the dupe you linked.

Comment: They have the exact same meaning.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness But it's 3 fewer characters and at the end of the day isn't regular expression all about being terse? ;)