# Is there a way to have the same characters in a regex identified differently

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to write a regex that would pick out numbers from a string of numbers and arithmetic operators, I was able to achieve that. Although, I want to expand the functionality of the program to match a number at the beginning that takes this kind of format: `+32`.

This is the initial regex:
`([\d.A-Z√\s]+)|([-+x÷])`. 
And this is  what I've achieved:
`([+]?[\d.A-Z√\s]+)([-+x÷])`

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Just to match any number with a + before ?

Comment: To match the first number of the String with a + before

Comment: But what does the question title mean?  In other words, what does matching a number have to do with "have the same character in a regex identified differently"?

Comment: The `+` symbol in the second capturing group is shadowing the `+` in the first capturing group

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex - overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971466/java-regex-overlapping-matches)

Comment: Here is a string of numbers and arithmetic operators - will you need your regex to handle this? — `+12 - 5 + -13 + +22 - +7` -- it will depend on your goal, _why_ you need this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider your sample `+123+45+67` and the initial regex `([\d.A-Z√\s]+)|([-+x÷])`.

### Option 1

By adding `(?:^[-+]|)` group, you can include leading `+` and `-` characters into the first match ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iHVQXs/2)):

```regex
((?:^[-+]|)[\d.A-Z√\s]+)|([-+x÷])
```

That regex will match:

```
+123
+
45
+
67
```

### Option 2

If you also need to capture the first number without leading `+`, `-` characters, I'd use another group for that, to avoid the problem with overlapping matches ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yu3ZYe/2)).

```regex
((?:^[-+]|)([\d.A-Z√\s]+))|([-+x÷])
```

This regex captures:

- Group 1: number including unary operator, if the operator exists
- Group 2: number without unary operator
- Group 3: operator, if any

```
match  group1  group2  group3 
 +123    +123     123      
    +                       +
   45      45      45
    +                       +
   67      67      67
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave out the bar?

((?:\A+)?[\d.A-Z√\s]+)|([-+x÷])

Treats the + as being part of the second 'operators' group, unless preceded by start of string, a (, or a [.

Comment: Its matches are similar to my those of my first regex

Comment: You should clarify with examples of what should and shouldn't be matched.

Comment: `123` should be one of the matches in `+123+45+67` as well as `+123`